# Audio equalizer circuit using multiple feedback bandpass filter for each frequency band

Tags: circuit-design, gain, active-filter, 741-opamp

I have a project to design an audio equalizer circuit with the following specifications.

- Bass band, center frequency = 180 hz, quality factor =0.7, range of adjustable gain 0.4-8
- Midrange band, center frequency = 1 khz, quality factor =0.7, range of adjustable gain 0.2-4
- Treble band, center frequency = 5.5 khz, quality factor =0.7, range of adjustable gain 0.1-2

[image]

I did the calculations to satisfy the center frequency and quality factors, but I am not understanding the range of adjustable gain.

I only have 6- LM741 op amps (I understand the 741 is vintage, it is all I have, I'm just a college student. Trying to make it.) I don't understand where to fit my potentiometers.

Initially I thought I could place a variable gain inverting amplifier after each filter, but I then thought I would need a summing amplifier to combine the inverted outputs and that would be one two many op amps.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably wasting your time using the 1968 vintage 741. [Read this](https://sound-au.com/articles/eq.htm)

Comment: I don't think he is asking about component selection.

Comment: A single summing amplifier can have individually adjustable gains for each input, by making the input resistor variable.  If the feedback resistor is 16 K, then the math for the input resistor ranges is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @AnalogKid the op said this: *Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.* I also linked to a great article on Baxandall tone controls so reconsider your comment.

Comment: @AnalogKid So I can take the output of each filter and place a potentiometer then combine them into a summing amplifier?

Comment: Compare "....wasting your time using the 1968 vintage 741. Read this" which inadvertently makes it look like the link is there to support the 741 caution vs "...wasting your time using the 1968 vintage 741. Read this for practical equalizer circuits" which makes it clear there's so much more.

Comment: I understand the 741 is vintage, it is all I have, I'm just a college student. Trying to make it.

Comment: It's possible that the idea of having three fixed bands EQ is selected randomly. If in addition the idea is to use the same eq construction in several channels in an audio mixer the result would be unsatisfying. In that case consider to have at least sweepable midrange and shelving bass&treble. BTW 741 causes so much bad distortion in transients that the sound will be very stumpy. 741 based audio equipment were considered to be crap quite soon after they became available.

Comment: @Andyaka, the last sentence of the article you linked to should be: "Varying **[frequency]** is used to create vibrato (cyclically varying pitch) which _is_ audible, and is used as an 'effect' with many electric musical instruments."
See [tremolo and vibrato](https://www.fender.com/articles/tech-talk/pitch-or-volume-the-difference-between-tremolo-and-vibrato).

Comment: @tim not sure why you are telling me this.

Comment: Most people use a simple "3-way tone controls" circuit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just a note: When designing these filters, one can set the center frequency, Q, and maximum gain at the center frequency. By choosing the capacitors to be equal, you have given up the ability to independently choose the gain at the center frequency.
2. These filters have to be driven by a low impedance source for accuracy, so you can’t put a pot in FRONT of them, unless you want to add a buffer after each pot.
3. It makes the most sense, then, to use a 4th op amp as an inverting summer after these stages to provide independent gain controls for the three channels. The 3 pots would be the input resistors for this summing stage, connected as variable resistors. Fixed resistors in series with the pots determine the maximum gain. Choose the pot values and feedback resistor value appropriately to meet your gain specs.

Comment: I noticed that the adjustable gain of the midrange is double the adjustable gain of the treble, and the adjustable gain of the bass is double the adjustable gain of the midrange, so if my Rf is a set value than will any combined resistance of the potentiometer and an input resistor simply need to be within the range of the respective gain values?

Comment: I will do the first one for you: the gain of the bass channel you designed is -1. You need a max gain of 8. So, use 80k for Rf, the fixed input resistor is 10k, the adjustable resistor is 0 ohm to 190k. Now, you do the rest. ( this is likely homework?)

Comment: Your filters only boost a very wide bandpass, they do not cut.

Answer (score 0):

Today is two years later and I simulated the mids filter and see that its peak is too narrow and its slopes are too gradual:
[image: MF filter]